# How to uninstall windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I have 4 drives in my hard drive. I have installed another Windows-8 same version in my PC and in other Drive. Now I want to delete this windows version which I installed second time please suggest me how to remove it.

Edit: I have installed the second windows in a logical drive.

Comment: Please tell me how I got a downvote?

Comment: someone felt you needed to do more research. I personally felt that it WAS pretty interesting since its unclear if either of the bcd editing tools I know of supported windows 8 and I learnt that msconfig has made  boot loader editing slightly simpler than it was before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot into the partition you want to keep. You're going to want to edit the bootloader to only have the OS install you want so hit <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> -  <kbd>R</kbd>  and type in 'msconfig' there.

You need to go to the boot tab and remove any OSes you don't want

[image]

Be very careful here since if you remove the wrong one you may render the system unbootable. It should be logical not to since it shows what's the current OS, and what's the default OS :). Set the current OS to default if it isn't, select the other one, and delete it. This should keep it from booting.

You can then format the partition, and use a third party disk management tool if you want to add it to the main partition.

Comment: I opened boot.ini but got confused. This one is the perfect solution thanks

Answer (score 1):

Delete all files, and format the disk with desired Windows installation. Now, reboot and [fix the MBR](https://www.google.com/search?q=fixmbr) of your system.

Answer (score 0):

So you currently are dual booting?

Delete the partition with your second windows using [partition magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PartitionMagic) or something similar (There is probably a free alternative available, I really only know the linux ones).

Alternatively you could just wipe the computer and start from scratch (which is possible using the only the windows CD)

Comment: I cant start all over again. I lost my product key.